# Visual Studio 2010 Object Not Set To An Instance Of An Object

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I know that there are numerous questions like this out there but I have yet to see anything matching my issue.  First I did install Visual Studio 2012 RC (since uninstalled).  Whenever I build in either VS 2010 or 2012, I get "object not set to an instance of an object" but only when publishing a website.

When I turn on Diagnostic Debugging, the solution builds with no errors and this error occurs when pushing the App_Code folder.  This same solution never had this error, it came out of nowhere and I cannot figure out how to fix things.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2010, I have manually copied all of the code out of all of the web pages and middle tiers class libraries into a new project.  I have tried everything and am at a loss as to how to fix this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at the stack trace? If so, can you post it?

Comment: A few things.  First the stack trace, no matter what level of debugging, always crashed when it got to Publishing App_Code...  Second, if I ran the solution more than once and then tried to publish, I kept getting conflicts in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and there were multiple build folders therein.  In my App_Code folder I was placing a WCF Service to support some backend integration.  As soon as I removed that the site built without any issues.  I now need to figure out why that worked and how to get the WCF Service back into the solution.